# Convert text to number in Google Sheets & Excel

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, string-formatting, number-formatting, flatten

How can i convert these strings to numbers in google sheets & excel, considering the columns is a mixture of billions and millions.
$9B
$100M
$100M
$90B

Comment: Are each number in a different cell? I mean, is the formula you need something to convert "$9B" to 9000000000, next cell "$100M" to 100000000 and so on?

Comment: yes, i want to convert B's to 9 '0' & M to 6 '0'.The strings are in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&""; "M");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4; "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000; 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&""; "k");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4; "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000;
 IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A4&""; "B");
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A4; "\d+.\d+|\d+")*1000000000; A1:A4))))
```

[image]

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya
 Should i use the 6 formulas or choose one randomly?

Comment: @AnthonyNdungu that is one single formula (just on six rows)

Comment: @AnthonyNdungu https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DVd4WTnTcCZaqmRj20PDlqVISD1xYPDzZBzW8qFRDFc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

For the columns whose values are consistence eg $100B, $10B, $4B...and so on this formula works **=SPLIT(lower(A3),"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm`-=[];',./!@#$%^&*()")** in google sheets.